# Full animated order book

Tags: charts

I have been using [this Clark Moody webpage](http://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/) to track the price of Bitcoin on MtGox. A nice animated order book is provided, along with a good chart.

Are there similar pages but for other exchanges (because MtGox...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about http://bitcoinwisdom.com/? It visualizes data from 14 different exchanges.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite: https://bitcoinity.org/markets/mtgox/USD

**16 exchanges**

- huobi
- btce
- bitstamp
- btcchina
- mtgox
- bitfinex
- kraken
- bitcurex
- cavirtex
- localbitcoins
- campbx
- justcoin
- bit2c
- bitquick
- rmbtb
- icbit

**20 currencies**

- AUD
- CAD
- CHF
- CNY
- DKK
- EUR
- GBP
- HKD
- ILS
- JPY
- KRW
- NOK
- NZD
- PLN
- RUB
- RUR
- SEK
- SGD
- THB
- USD

**10 time spans**

- 10 minutes
- 1 hour
- 3 hours
- 12 hours
- 24 hours
- 3 days
- 7 days
- 30 days
- 6 month
- 1 year
- 2 years

Answer (score 2):

List of all sites I know of

1. http://bitcointicker.co/
2. http://bitcoinwisdom.com/
3. http://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/
4. http://www.coinorama.net/ (only graphical order book)
5. http://bitjoy.org/~ (order book in "to do" list)

Answer (score 0):

Clark Moody is what I choose for quick glance as it offers basic candlesticks, MA and orderbook but orderbook is not visualised (as far as I can see), anyways if You want deeper in both directions:

- http://www.tradingview.com is the very robust advanced technical charting + all asset classes
- http://btccharts.com is very advanced bitcoin orderbook actually visualised

both have access to major Bitcoin exchanges, and are free.