# Is there a chart of all combined orderbooks?

Tags: exchanges, charts

I would like to view a chart where all bid/asks are combined from the various exchanges, instead of keeping multiple tabs open for each exchange. Is there a website that allows this kind of meta-overview?

Answer (score 1):

All of the exchanges have APIs http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=155
you can create a script to keep the numbers updated with wget and a cron job
Cryptsy has a pusher API for live updates.
https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/pushapi

Answer (score 0):

1. [data.bitcoinity.org](https://data.bitcoinity.org/markets/books/USD) has come up with such a website:

[image]

2. There is also a combined depth chart at http://bitcointicker.co/, but it is not actually clear if it is actually combined from more exchanges (and which ones) or if it is from single exchange.
3. There are some code projects on this topic, like: https://github.com/coinorama/coinorama/wiki/Coinorama or https://github.com/Pechalka/combined-order-book/
4. You find more (though old) answers here: [Full animated order book](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/19882/82628)